# How does eternal inflation (from a possibly finite space-time region) produce infinitely large pocket universes?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, multiverse

The title almost already completely captures my question: In reviews and summaries of eternal inflation models, it is typically stated that the arising pocket universes (to be precise: the space-time patches in which inflation ends locally, reheating happens and a hot universe arises) are infinite, even if the initial space-time region that was inflating eternally may have been finite. This statement puzzles me a lot.

I found a very small part of this [Tegmark paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0410281.pdf)  that seems to claim to explain this briefly in its VII D section:

> Consider a single-field inflaton potential $V(\phi)$ with a peak
> (local maximum) at $\phi = 0$, and a comoving spatial region where the
> inflaton potential varies extremely slowly in the $x$-direction:
> $\phi(x, y, z) \approx\epsilon x$, where the constant $\epsilon$ is so
> small that spatial gradients in $\phi$ are negligible. If quantum
> diffusion is negligible, then inflation will eventually end everywhere
> in our comoving region except at the one point $\phi = 0$, but it
> clearly takes longer for $\phi$ to roll off the peak and end inflation
> the closer to $\phi = 0$ it starts. In the slow-roll approximation and
> considering the very top of the peak where it can be approximated by
> an upside down parabola, one readily finds that the number of
> e-foldings required to roll down from $\phi$ is given by ([see the
> corresponding] Appendix B.2) $$e^{N(\phi)} \propto |\phi|^{\eta^{−1}},$$ where $\eta\equiv m^2V''(0)/V(0)$ is the usual
> slow-roll parameter at the origin. The total thermalized volume
> produced by our comoving region is thus $$V \propto \int e^{3N(\phi(\vec{r}))}dV \propto\int e^{3N(|\epsilon x|)}dx \propto\int |x|^{3\eta^{−1}} dx,$$ which will diverge near the origin and
> give an infinite volume as long as $\eta > −3$.

However, while I understand why the final integral diverges, I do not really understand the assumptions of this proof, especially not the assumption $\phi\approx\epsilon x$, an assumption I never say (why should the field be proportional to a spatial component...?), but this is the ingredient that produces the divergence.

If anyone can help with this particular 'proof', or knows any other, I am grateful for help. Please no pure heuristic arguments, I am interesting in some rigor regarding this problem.

Comment: I may post a full answer tomorrow with full analysis, but Linde's book "Particle Physics and Inflationary Cosmology" has a very thorough explanation of eternal inflation.  It's open source now on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0503203 The crux of the argument can be found in section 1.8. The argument is different than the paper you linked, but the basic idea is that (locally inhomogeneous) quantum fluctuations of $\phi$ are significant enough beyond a specific value so that it is "pushed back up", meaning areas of larger $\phi$ inflate for longer, thus dominating most of the Universe.

Comment: @rhomaios Thanks for your comment. I am aware of Linde's book. As I understand, your comment explains the mechanism how (slow-roll) inflation actually becomes eternal. I do not understand how it explains that pocket universes are infinite, though.

Comment: As far as I understand, if the inflating space goes on expanding forever, there are always inflationary patches within it that due to the inhomogeneous nature of the fluctuations and the classical slow roll of $\phi$ manage to meet the conditions to exit inflation. Since inflation is eternal, patches exiting inflation are also eternal, meaning you end up with infinite mini-universes.